# Azure Databricks error: AzureException: hadoop_azure_shaded.com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: Server failed to authenticate the request

Tags: python, sql, azure, apache-spark

I am trying to execute this command and in a lot of scenarios, it returns me this error.

`spark.sql("""drop table if exists """ + L2_STAGE + """.STERLING_INCREMENT_STAGE_DELTA""") dbutils.fs.rm("dbfs:/mnt/data/governed/l2/stage/order/dtc_mergedstage/", true) spark.sql("""drop table if exists """ + L2_STAGE + """.sterling_increment_stage_delta_ol""") dbutils.fs.rm("dbfs:/mnt/data/governed/l2/stage/order/order_line_stg/", true) spark.sql("""drop table if exists """ + L2_STAGE + """.STERLING_INCREMENT_STAGE_DELTA_str""") dbutils.fs.rm("dbfs:/mnt/data/governed/l2/stage/order/dtc_mergedstage_str/", true) spark.sql("""drop table if exists """ + L2_STAGE + """.sterling_increment_stage_delta_ol_str""") dbutils.fs.rm("dbfs:/mnt/data/governed/l2/stage/order/order_line_stg_str/", true)`

This returns me this error:

*AzureException: hadoop_azure_shaded.com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
Caused by: StorageException: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.*

Can someone let me know what is wrong? The administrator says that the access levels for all my colleagues are same and he doesn't know how to resolve. I don't know if this is a problem to be resolved from Databricks or through Azure Portal.

I also realize that:

- Error occurs when I try to read from a table, or when I try to drop a table. But I can create tables.
- I can perform this command:

```
%fs
ls /mnt/edap/data/governed
```

without error.

But,

```
%fs
ls /mnt/data/governed
```

gives same error.

**'edap' is an Azure Blob container.

I hope someone can help resolve that error.

Comment: Could you please  tell me how you mount the container?

Comment: Him Jim! Thanks for your comment. All I had to do was unmount it and it worked. It was my first time using it and I just did a mistake and didn't know what to do about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't quite aware and noticed that I had mounted a drive and only had to unmount it in order to get things working. I had to navigate in DBFS to the path where I had mounted. The mounted drive a had a different icon, like a container or a flask, while the others had a folder icon. I clicked on the drop down and unmounted it. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the path `/mnt/data/` should point to a storage container somewhere in your organization's Azure tenancy. Further, I am assuming that you intend for the data to live on containers that your organization controls.

I believe that you have not solved your problem. At present, your tables are most likely being written to a file path in `dbfs:` (the container set aside for your Databricks instance) rather than to your organization's Azure containers.

The command `%fs ls /mnt/edap/data/governed` works because it is pointed at the  `/mnt/edap` container, which is correctly mounted. Similarly, `%fs ls /mnt/data/` will now work because it is pointed at a directory in `dbfs:` where permissions are not an issue.

The problem is that the container for `/mnt/data/` was not mounted correctly in the first place.

Here is the mistake I made that generated the same error:

I attempted to mount the container using the instructions here: https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/azure-storage.html

However, the container I was attempting to mount existed in a Azure Gen2 datalake. The correct method of mounting the container can be found here: https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/adls-gen2/azure-datalake-gen2-sp-access.html

If the container in question is truly just a blob storage instance, double check your code for mounting the container.